# HTML5 Video Overlap -- With buttons clickable

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a video that I'm displaying onto a website and use HTML5 Video.   What I want to do is have the overlap, however, I would like to have a button/link that when you click it takes you to find more information.

E.g.

```css
.outer-container {
    border: 1px dotted black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.inner-container {
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.video-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
}
video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
    <div class="inner-container">
        <div class="video-overlay">Bug Buck Bunny - Trailer  
         <br />
         <br />
          
          <a href="http://www.google.com">Find out more</a>
        </div>
        <video id="player" controls
        src="http://video.webmfiles.org/big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm" autoplay loop></video>
    </div>
</div>
```

The link does not actually work. I cannot for the life of me understand why not as it's contained within a div. Is this functionality possible? Want to hopefully try to avoid using javascript to force a link.

Comment: Just add `z-index: 5` or increase it to make the link clickable.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Thanks! Now I feel stupid! It was just that haha

Answer (score 0):

You've gotta z-index that button.

```
.video-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.3);
    z-index: 5;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5n1vvzee/

You're absolutely positioning that button, and because of the document flow, the video container is conceptually covering it up, even though it's still visible.

**edit**

@JonasGrumann raises a good point in the comments.  Assigning random numbers for z-index values is a bad practice. If you're utilizing a modern CSS framework like Bootstrap, it generally has these values handled for you via utility classes or SASS/LESS variables in the framework.

If you're not utilizing one of these frameworks, it's wise to make a habit of adding comments somewhere at the top of your CSS file to designate z-index levels and use them accordingly throughout your files.

Comment: Speaking from experience, using z-index: 9999; is not a good idea, you'll end up with a z-index nightmare, especially in IE, I'd go with something like z-index: 1;